# Unit test assembly binding issue in IDE, but not in command line

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, vstest

I have setup a unit test project using MSTest v2, where there is a test method that fails when it is executed via Visual Studio IDE. Apparently some runtime assembly binding is failing. It has been hard to track it.

So I decide to run the same test in command line, using vstest.console. And the test executes great!.

What would be the context differences so we have such behavior? How vstest.console differs from running from VS2017 IDE? How to narrow down this issue?

Comment: Any detail more than "there is a test method that fails"?

Comment: well, this specific test method is some kind of integration test that invokes a third-part API, with several third-party dependencies. It seems this API has some kind of factory and during the loading of the assemblies an exception is thrown, saying that one of the assemblies (or its dependencies) cannot be found. But if the test runs successfully when executed by vstest.console.exe than I assume nothing is missing.

Comment: "Hard to track"? Have you checked Fusion log? Also the best channel would be MSTest v2 repo, https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues You can let them know that you hit this issue only when using the VS runner.

Comment: I need to go deeper into Fusion Log, but it shows some binding issues. My understanding for the binding errors I got is that some dlls were not found. Actually they are inside bin/debug folder, but for some reason they are being probed inside the test adapter nuget package "build" folder. Have no idea why this behavior..

Comment: The VS runner is launched by VS from the NuGet package folder. You might check Fusion log to see whether that triggers the issue. If the issue can then be confirmed, report to Microsoft repo and see if there is a workaround for you to use.

Comment: I replace the mstest.testadapter and mstest.testframework nugget packages by the vs.qualitytools.unittestframework package and visual studio could run successfully. Could we say this seems to be something between VS and MSTest v2?

Comment: Another test I did was to use MSTest.TestAdapter 1.3.1 (not latest) and MSTest.TestFramework 1.3.2 (latest) and then the test was executed fine.